# What exactly does it mean to "sign in" a user in Open ID Connect

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect

I'm currently studying OAuth 2.0 and OpenID Connect protocols, and  there is something I feel I'm missing. Let's start with setting the stage:

Briefly, we have OAuth 2.0, which define a mechanism in which *client applications* can get access to *resources* located on a *resource server* on behalf of a user. This is done by redirecting the user-agent to an *authorization server*, where the user grants permissions (scopes) to the client application. The client application then receives an *authorization code*, which can be used to redeem and *access token* and optionally an *ID token*.

Here we come to talk about OpenID Connect. OIDC is a thin layer on top of OAuth 2.0, which adds a scope named `openid`, which when granted, allows the client application to ask and receive an *ID token* - which contains some basic information about the user. This is used by applications to *authenticate* users.

I have introduced mainly the *authorization code flow*, and I am aware that there are other flows to OAuth 2.0.

Hoping that the above gives a decent description of the concepts, what I'm now trying to understand is - what does it mean exactly for a user to "sign in" to an application (I mean - a client application)?

In my understanding, it may be that when a client application requests an `openid` scope - i.e., an ID token - and saves one of the claims in the token which uniquely identifies the user in a `session` object, but I'm not sure that's true.

Can someone explain?

Comment: When you send them to the `/authorization` endpoint and they are not signed in, they typically get presented with a login form.

Comment: If you did already understand that part of the flow, perhaps you can elaborate a bit more on what 'signing in to the client application' means to you and what the relevance is of this question.

Answer (score 0):

With signing, you ask the user to authenticate and after a successful authentication including giving consent for the application to get access to the  requested scopes.

But OpenID Connect does not define how you authenticate your users, its up to you! It can be username/password, it can be hardware keys, it can be certificates, it can be through social login (using like Google or Facebook...)

With OpenID Connect, you must ask for the **openid** scope and all it will return in the id-token is the **sub** claim (the unique user id).

After the client application receives the token, it typically creates a cookie session with the user based on the information in the ID-token. After that the ID-token have no longer any purpose. The lifetime of the id token is usually rather short, like 5 minutes in some systems.